# Android studio :: Unable to see a source folder

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I recently migrated my project to Android studio. I have placed all my library source folders under Application/library/src/main/java.

There is one folder named "rcs". I can see it in my windows explorer. But, I cannot see it in Android studio project view or any other views. And I can see that, wherever I refer the contents of this folder, I am seeing "Cannot resolve symbol" for this particular folder.

But I see those files are compiled and present in the "exploded-aar" folder of my application folder. Just that, they are not present in the project explorer.

Please input your suggestions. I don't have a classpath or .cvsignore or .gitignore.

Comment: Does your Gradle file compile anything from `Application/library`?

Comment: yes, it compiles fine.. Just that in the "project explorer" view, the folders aren't seen. And also in import statements, those folder paths are not recognized. Also I am not seeing those files in the search results.

Comment: Also, when I try to create a folder named "rcs", it says: "Trying to create a directory with an ignored name. Result will not be visible."

Comment: Is this is "rcs" is a sub  folder in java class?

Comment: Yes, fixed it rogerwar. Thanks much. Answer posted below.

Answer (score 1):

Folder named "rcs" was ignored by Studio as its a version control system. Fixed it by changing:

Go to File `>` Settings `>` Editor `>` File Types `>` ”Ignore files and folders”.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using new android studio, check this[image]

Answer (score -1):

Just go to build->clean project->Build Project

Comment: Tried. Doesn't help.

Comment: Also, when I try to create a folder named "rcs", it says: "Trying to create a directory with an ignored name. Result will not be visible."